# How to perform groupby in Pandas and compute mean of each row in original dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a spreadsheet which has data in the following format:

```
Brand | Model    | Year | Cost  | Tax
--------------------------------------
Apple | iPhone 7 | 2017 | $1000 | $100

Apple | iphone 7 | 2018 | $800  |  $80

Xiomi | Note 5   | 2017 | $300  |  $30

Xiomi | Note 5   | 2018 | $200  |  $20
```

I want to transform the above data set to the following where I want to show `Mean` of Cost column when rows are grouped by `['Brand', 'Model']` and a **Result** column which is the sum of `Mean` and `Tax` column values:

```
Brand | Model    | Year | Cost  | Mean   | Tax    |  Result
------------------------------------------------------------ 
Apple | iPhone 7 | 2017 | $1000 | $900   | $100   |  $1000

Apple | iphone 7 | 2018 | $800  | $900   | $80    |  $980

Xiomi | Note 5   | 2017 | $300  | $250   | $30    |  $280

Xiomi | Note 5   | 2018 | $200  | $250   | $25    |  $275
```

I have been trying with [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) function but not getting a way to get the desired result as above.

Looking forward to your responses. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert values to integers with `replace`, get `mean` by [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html), then `sum` and last convert back to strings if necessary:

```
cols = ['Cost','Tax']
df[cols] = df[cols].replace('\$','', regex=True).astype(int)
df['Mean'] = df.groupby(['Brand', 'Model'])['Cost'].transform('mean')

df['Result'] = df[['Mean','Tax']].sum(axis=1)
print (df)
   Brand     Model  Year  Cost  Tax  Mean  Result
0  Apple  iPhone 7  2017  1000  100  1000    1100
1  Apple  iphone 7  2018   800   80   800     880
2  Xiomi    Note 5  2017   300   30   250     280
3  Xiomi    Note 5  2018   200   20   250     270
```

And then:

```
cols1 = cols + ['Result', 'Mean']
df[cols1] = '$' + df[cols1].astype(str)
print (df)
   Brand     Model  Year   Cost   Tax   Mean Result
0  Apple  iPhone 7  2017  $1000  $100  $1000  $1100
1  Apple  iphone 7  2018   $800   $80   $800   $880
2  Xiomi    Note 5  2017   $300   $30   $250   $280
3  Xiomi    Note 5  2018   $200   $20   $250   $270
```